# Zombie film with airborne disease. Protagonists head toward safety at the coast

Tags: story-identification, movie, zombie

I'm trying to recall the name of a zombie movie I saw a couple years ago. I can only remember snippets, but I remember that the people who succumbed to the (airborne) disease would show symptoms.

In one scene, a character was laying dead on the floor and then a couple minutes went by and she opened her eyes and looked at the person next to her and then attacked.

I also remember a scene in an apartment building, a zombie man was in an apartment and the character was on the hallway and the zombie looked, opened the door and chased him.

I also remember they had to make it to the beach because they believed the winds there would hinder the disease.

Comment: Welcome to Science Fiction & Fantasy! This question would be improved by going through the checklists here; [How to ask a good story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question)

Comment: Possibly one of these; https://www.ranker.com/list/best-horror-movies-about-viruses-and-diseases/ranker-film or these https://www.imdb.com/list/ls006279353/

Answer (score 3):

[*Carriers*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carriers_(film)) (filmed in 2006, released in 2009).

The plot is some what similar as they go to the beach and want to start a new life. There are several places they visit,  so it might be one of the scenes you mention.

I saw the movie some years ago,  one of the few with zombies and traveling to the beach.

Answer (score 1):

Partial match: *Descendentes* or *Solos*, a 2008 Chilean movie.

From [IMDb](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt1361838/):

> In an undefined future, the earth has been destroyed by man, and the air polluted with a mysterious virus that turns humans into zombies. Only a few children are immune to the disease and have adapted to these extreme conditions and survived. Camille, a nine year old girl wanders through these desolate wastelands, protecting herself from zombies and the armed military forces that roam the land killing anyone who might be infected. However, the little girl will find other kids like her that share a recurring dream of: they all have visions of the ocean as their destiny. **Together they will try to survive the journey to the ocean in search of an escape from the military who seem to be as determined on their destruction as on the zombies.**

Warning, the trailer is very graphic:

I'm putting it as an answer as there does not seem to be many zombie movies with a "survivors must go to some beach" plot, so it may be useful to future readers; however, it's probably not the exact movie the question is referring to, as the children travel to the beach not because of winds hindering, but because the main character's dying mother instructed her to.

---

Found with the query `future portal zombie` on [whatismymovie.com](http://whatismymovie.com/results?text=future+portal+zombie), filtered by "Traditional search" results; I was actually looking for an answer to [Movie: in a big seaside city time travel portals open to the apocalyptic future with the fading sun and zombie mutants](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/228568), but the bit about the ocean made me remember the present question.